Bun `build --compile` with embedded assets
I'm experimenting with embedding assets into executable. The executable successfully logs the JSON file's content even if the executable is moved elsewhere. However, the file does not appear in the embeddedFiles variable.
Is this expected behaviour? I'm following the documentation but can't find any clues.
bun v1.1.42
index.ts
import Bun from "bun";

import test from "./test.json";

console.log(Bun.embeddedFiles);
console.log(test);

test.json
{ "foo": "bar" }

$ bun build --compile index.ts
  [4ms]  bundle  2 modules
  [48ms] compile  index
$ ./index
[]
{
  foo: "bar",
}

EDIT:
I tested with an assertion using import test from "./test.json" with { type: "json" }; and got the same results:
$ ./index
[]
{
  foo: "bar",
}

However, when I used import test from "./test.json" with { type: "file" }; it worked as expected:
$ ./index
[
  Blob (20 bytes) {
    name: "test-zg4jz7gq.json",
    type: "application/json;charset=utf-8"
  }
]
/$bunfs/root/test-zg4jz7gq.json

However, the output isn't serialized because it doesn't recognize the JSON type.

Note that you don't import with your JSON file - that hints that JSON is considered a source file, just like JS, and so does not appear on the list of embedded files.

@STerliakov I tested with the json type, but the results were the same. Interestingly, it worked with the file type, though the output wasn't serialized.

So JSON type is apparently just a source file, not a file to be embedded. That's likely a design decision, consider opening a ticket to clarify that in the docs.

Perhaps, but the strange thing about this is that it's actually embedded, yet it isn't being recognized at embeddedFiles

Yep, but that doesn't sound strange to me: none of .js files are listed there too. They are code itself, not smth embedded into it, and imported JSON is treated the same way.
